# Adding constructor to Boost.Python subclass causes argument mismatch error

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I'm trying to use Python as a scripting language for a C++ project of mine, so I reached for Boost.Python to make the task less tedious. I have a C++ class (ScriptSystem) which is responsible for holding references to and executing Python scripts.

```
namespace py = boost::python;

class ScriptSystem : public System
{
    public:
    virtual void execute_scripts() override;

    void addToPyGlobals(const OtherSystemsPtr&);
    void addScript(IScript*);

    private:
    std::vector<IScript *> scripts;
    py::dict python_globals;        
};
```

The Python scripts are supposed to be subclasses of a wrapped C++ interface named IScript.

```
class IScript
{
    public:
    virtual ~IScript() {}

    // This function is meant to be overridden. It prints
    // to the console for debugging purposes only.
    virtual void tick() const {
        cout << "Default Implementation." << endl;
    }
};
```

I managed to expose the ScriptSystem class and the IScript interface to Python, and it almost sorta kinda works. I can create new instances of IScript and pass them to ScriptSystem without any trouble. I can create subclasses which override `tick(self)` and as long as they **don't define a constructor** I'm good to go.

```
namespace py = boost::python;

class ScriptWrapper : public Script::IScript, public py::wrapper<Script::IScript>
{
    public:
    void tick()const override
    {
        // Check for Python override
        if(py::override f = this->get_override("tick")) {
            std::cout << "Found Python override"
                      << std::endl;
            f();
            return;
        }

        // If there is no override, call the default implementation
        std::cout << "No Python override found, calling C++ implementation." 
                  << std::endl;
        this->Script::IScript::tick();
        return;
    }

    void default_tick() const {
        return this->Script::IScript::tick();
    }
};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(_script)
{
    py::class_<ScriptSystem, boost::noncopyable>("ScriptSystem")
        .def("add_script", &ScriptSystem::addScript);

    py::class_<ScriptWrapper, boost::noncopyable>("Script")
        .def("tick", &Script::IScript::tick, &ScriptWrapper::default_tick);

    py::implicitly_convertible<ScriptWrapper*, Script::IScript*>();
}
```

I can add data attributes to the class, but adding `__init__(self)` causes problems. For example, this code snippet executes just fine:

```
(RemoteShell)
>>> from script import Script
>>> class One(Script):
...     def tick(self):
...             print "I'm a script!"
...             print "My value is {}".format(One.value)
... 
>>> One.value = 5
>>> one = One()              
>>> script_system.add_script(one)
```

But this code fails:

```
(RemoteShell)
>>> from script import Script
>>> class Two(Script):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.count = 0
...     def tick(self):
...             if self.count % 2 == 0:
...                     print "Tick"
...             else:
...                     print "Tock"
...             self.count += 1
... 
>>> two = Two()
>>> script_system.add_script(two)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    ScriptSystem.add_script(ScriptSystem, Two)
did not match C++ signature:
    add_script(ScriptSystem {lvalue}, Script::IScript*)
```

So, I guess my question is: What is happening here?! I don't understand why adding a constructor to a Python subclass of Script (the python wrapper for IScript) causes an argument mismatch error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a derived class provides an [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method, then it must explicitly call its base class `__init__` methods to ensure proper initialization of the base class part of the instance.  In this case, the `Script` part of an instance of `Two` is not properly initialized, causing Boost.Python is fail dispatching based on the C++ types.

To resolve the problem, consider changing:

```python
class Two(Script):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
```

to:

```python
class Two(Script):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        Script.__init__(self)
```

---

Here is a complete minimal example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup type.
class spam {};

/// @brief Mockup function that takes spam types.
void action(spam*) {}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<spam>("Spam");
  python::def("action", &action);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> example.action(example.Spam())
>>> class MoreSpam(example.Spam):
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> example.action(MoreSpam())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    example.action(MoreSpam)
did not match C++ signature:
    action(spam*)
>>> class EvenMoreSpam(example.Spam):
...     def __init__(self):
...         example.Spam.__init__(self)
... 
>>> example.action(EvenMoreSpam())
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you very much! Your example was also quite helpful.